# http://127.0.0.1:8000/ isn't working on Chrome but working fine on Internet Explorer

Tags: django, python-3.x, windows-server-2012-r2

I've recently installed django on Windows Server 2012 R2.

When I run  `python manage.py runserver` it tell mes to use `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` . Its working on Internet explorer but in Firefox and Chrome I get the following error.

```
The requested URL could not be retrieved

The following error was encountered while trying to retrieve the URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Connection to 127.0.0.1 failed.

The system returned: (111) Connection refused

The remote host or network may be down. Please try the request again.

Your cache administrator is administrator.
```

Comment: Is this a home or an office machine?

Comment: It seems you need to bypass proxy server for localhost. It might already be enabled in IE that's why it is working there.

Comment: Bypass proxy wasn't enabled. It worked after enabling. @AKS Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bypass proxy wasn't enabled. It worked after enabling.